# Do not display duplicate result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my table register:

```
id  name         student_id  date     presence  absence_note    Tusername
50  hassimkhan    1112815    2014-03-08 P                        saahir
56  Karishma kods 1119112   2014-03-08  P                        saahir
58  Karishma kods 1119112   2014-03-09  P                        saahir           
60  hassimkhan    1112815   2014-03-09  A                        saahir
```

Here is my loop to display the result:

```
$retrieve = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(student_id),presence FROM register"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve))          
        {
             echo $row['student_id'];
                }
```

I know for e.g **id** 56 and 58 with student_id: 1112815 record are different in a way, but i want to display it only one time e.g of result of these data:

```
1112815
1119112
```

Any help?

Comment: SELECT student_id,presence FROM register GROUP BY student_id

Comment: you are selecting DISTINCT across both `student_id` and `presence`.  IN your example, this would yield two distinct rows for id 1112815 since the presence value differs.  You should also not that your syntax is not correct, it should be `SELECT DISTINCT student_id, presence...`  You have not address what you want to do with differing values for `presence`.  As thing stand right now, the records in your result set are NOT duplicates.

Comment: Obligatory WARNING to NOT USE `mysql_` methods.

Comment: When more than one row exists for sam student_id, the value for presence column in the final result should come from which row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GROUP`ing instead:

`SELECT student_id, presence FROM register GROUP BY student_id`

(untested)

Comment: +1.  But it might be more straight-forward, easier to understand, leaving off the the `CONCAT()` function; just `SELECT student_id...`

Comment: You should not here that you will get unpredictable results for the presence field value.

Comment: Mike, while I agree with that, perhaps he just wants an aggregated list of student IDs - we can't necessarily rule that out.

Comment: @HalfCrazed Sure, but presumably there is a reason he is including `presence` in his select. If he just wanted de-duped list of student ids, then he could easily do `SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM register` and have no need for a `GROUP BY` at all.

Comment: Good catch. OP should probably provide the end result goals :D

Answer (score 0):

```
retrieve = mysql_query("SELECT student_id,presence FROM register GROUP BY student_id"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve))          
{
  echo $row['student_id'];
}
```

Comment: You should not here that you will get unpredictable results for the `presence` field value.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes I know that. But his requirement was not to repeat the student_id. There was no constraint as to the values for other columns need to come from which row if more than one row with same student_id exist

Comment: Sure, but presumably there is a reason he is including `presence` in his select.  If he just wanted de-duped list of student ids, then he could easily do `SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM register` and have no need for a `GROUP BY` at all.

Comment: @MikeBrant You are definitely right. Need to write another solution for him. Upvote for you mate